# Jekyll cannot locate an included file in main.scss or the file has an error

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-bootstrap

I am importing an open source CSS into Jekyllrb, everytime I do I get the same error which is

```
Your SCSS file `assets/main.scss` has an error on line 14: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/functions. Load paths: _sass /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-invalid-sass-or-scss/.
```

I have tried installing github pages locally to test, brought in the css instead of importing it and it still seems to be conflicting with what I believe the theme Minima and trying to read the scss file instead of the css in _site

Here is my gemlock file:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activejob (= 4.2.10)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.10)
      activemodel (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.10)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arel (6.0.4)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.0.0)
      execjs
    backports (3.11.3)
    bootstrap (4.0.0)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 6.0.3)
      popper_js (>= 1.12.9, < 2)
      sass (>= 3.5.2)
    builder (3.2.3)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    extras (0.3.0)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.5)
    fastimage (2.1.3)
    ffi (1.9.25)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    hootstrap (0.4.0)
      bootstrap (~> 4.0.0)
      rails (>= 4.2.0)
      sass-rails
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (3.8.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 1.14)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 1.7, < 4)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
    jekyll-admin (0.8.1)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      jekyll (~> 3.3)
      sinatra (~> 1.4)
      sinatra-contrib (~> 1.4)
    jekyll-archives (2.1.1)
      jekyll (>= 2.4)
    jekyll-assets (2.4.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      extras (~> 0.2)
      fastimage (~> 2.0, >= 1.8)
      jekyll (~> 3.1, >= 3.0)
      pathutil (>= 0.8)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      sprockets (~> 3.3, < 3.8)
    jekyll-compose (0.8.0)
      jekyll (~> 3.0)
    jekyll-feed (0.10.0)
      jekyll (~> 3.3)
    jekyll-sass-converter (1.5.2)
      sass (~> 3.4)
    jekyll-seo-tag (2.5.0)
      jekyll (~> 3.3)
    jekyll-watch (2.0.0)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    kramdown (1.17.0)
    liquid (4.0.0)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mercenary (0.3.6)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minima (2.5.0)
      jekyll (~> 3.5)
      jekyll-feed (~> 0.9)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.1)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.4)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    pathutil (0.16.1)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    popper_js (1.14.3)
    public_suffix (3.0.2)
    rack (1.6.10)
    rack-protection (1.5.5)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.10)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activejob (= 4.2.10)
      activemodel (= 4.2.10)
      activerecord (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.10)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rouge (3.1.1)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.5.7)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sinatra (1.4.8)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    sinatra-contrib (1.4.7)
      backports (>= 2.0)
      multi_json
      rack-protection
      rack-test
      sinatra (~> 1.4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  hootstrap
  jekyll (~> 3.8.2)
  jekyll-admin
  jekyll-archives
  jekyll-assets
  jekyll-compose
  jekyll-sass-converter
  minima (~> 2.0)
  tzinfo-data

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.3
```

And my config.yml I have

```
sass:
  style: compact # possible values: nested expanded compact compressed
```

my main.scss resides in the root folder.  It's like it wants to include/read the scss file instead of compiling it into the _site/css

Sometimes I get this error when I try to alter some of the sass which leads me to believe that the theme Minima is throwing me for a loop, too

```
Your SCSS file `main.scss` has an error on line 14: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap/functions. Load paths: _sass /hoosegow/.bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass
```

I don't know what to do from here to have it compile correct and work on github pages.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

The error is saying that you have an `import` statement in your `assets/main.scss` and that the file referenced in the statement *most probably* cannot be found (or is unreadable).

Check your project's root directory (not the `_site` directory), I think you have a `_sass` directory there. If so, update your `_config.yml` file to tell Jekyll where to find it. Assuming it is in the root directory and that the output is compressed, add the following:

```
sass:
  sass_dir: _sass
  style: compressed
```

Then, if the local Jekyll server is running, stop it. Delete the `_site` directory and rebuild the site.

Hopefully the build or serve command will not output this error anymore.

If the issue persists, please include the SCSS file in your question and also a screenshot of your project's directory, together with a screenshot of you `_site` directory structure once you've rebuilt it.